# Inconsistency between the 'predict' and 'predict_proba' methods of the python libSVM wrapper

Tags: python, machine-learning, libsvm

I'm using the libSVM python wrapper for a binary classifier prediction, and noticed that sometimes I'm getting different results from the 'predict' and 'predict_proba' methods.
To get the predicted class from 'predict_proba' returned matrix, I use this code for each instance:

```
return 0 if probs[0]>0.5 else 1
```

For example, for one instance the 'predict_proba' returned [[ 0.49179164,  0.50820836]],  the 'predict' method returned 1 as excepted. But for another instance, the 'predict' function returned 1, and the 'predict_proba' returned [[ 0.50822999,  0.49177001]], which implies the predicted class is 0 and not 1. To check which result is the right one, I called the 'decision_function' method, which returns the distance from the separating hyperplane. If it's positive, the class is 1, and 0 otherwise. The 'decision_function' returned 0.024, meaning the class is indeed 1 as the 'predict' method returned, meaning there is a bug in the 'predict_proba' method. To calculate the probabilities, I've used this code:

```
dist = classifier.decision_function(instance)
class1_prob = np.exp(dist)/(np.exp(dist)+np.exp(-dist))
probs = [[1-class1_prob, class1_prob]]
```

Most defiantly there is a bug, and I wonder if it's in the libSVM library or in the python wrapper. My intuition tells me that this dubious behavior is due to instances that are too close to the separating hyperplane.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint, hence community wiki: your version of `predict_proba` is not what is used inside LibSVM. Instead, it uses

```
static double sigmoid_predict(double decision_value, double A, double B)
{
        double fApB = decision_value*A+B;
        if (fApB >= 0)
                return exp(-fApB)/(1.0+exp(-fApB));
        else
                return 1.0/(1+exp(fApB)) ;
}
```

where the `A` and `B` values are determined by [Platt scaling](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639) during training.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've checked, and the predict_proba in the python wrapper is calling the function "_dense_predict_proba", which calls the libsvm.predict_proba function. So in my opinion it's a bug in libsvm.predict_proba.